# Prepend function of my recursive list creates an endless list

Tags: java, list, generics, recursion, generic-list

Currently, I'm working on a generic list in Java. Problem: The prepend method doesn't work the way it should. Instead of adding an element T at index 0 it's creating an endless recursive list.

```
public class Vector<T>{

    private T value;
    private Vector<T> next = null;

    public Vector(T value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Vector(T value, Vector<T> next){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void prepend(T element){
        this.next = this;
        this.value = element;
    }
}



public class Main{
    ...
    Vector<Integer> v1 = new Vector<Integer>(new Integer(1));
    v1.prepend(new Integer(0));
    ...
```

Expected output: {0,1}
Actual output: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0, ........ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing: First, you create a Vector with value = 1, next = null. „Prepending“ 0, you set next to this, an endless recursion, then you set value = 0. If you look at your Vector, you first get the value = 0. Then you change to the Vector next, which still is this. Of that „new“ Vector, you output value = 0. Then you change to the Vector next, which still is this. Of that „new“ Vector, you output value = 0. Then ... you get it.

What you most probably want to do: When prepending an Integer, you want to COPY this to next and set value to the new Integer. That would read:

```
public class Vector<T>{

[…]
    public void prepend(T element){
        this.next = new Vector<>(value, next); // a Copy Constructor would also be fine
        this.value = element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.next = this` creates a circular list of a single element.

You are trying to implement the list and a node of the list with the same class. You should use one class to represent the list (and hold a reference to the head of the list), and another class to represent a node of the list.

Your prepend method should create a new link instance. Then that new instance should become the new head of the list and its next should be the original head of the list.

```
public class Vector<T>{

    public static class Node<T> {
        private T value;
        private Node<T> next = null;
        ...
    }

    private Node<T> head;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, and the prepend method has to be in the Vector class but outside the Node class?

Comment: @cid in the Vector class, since it changes the `head` of the list.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated :**

Your prepend method is wrong. Your method should be like this if you don't want to save the head of the list.

```
public void prepend(T element){
    Vector<T> val = new Vector<T>(element);
    val.next = this.next;
    this.next = val; // after this statement new Element at inserted at 1 position. 
    // Swap the values
    val.value = this.value;
    this.value = element;
}
```

And in main create a vector

```
Vector<Integer> v1 = new Vector<Integer>(new Integer(1));
v1.prepend(new Integer(0));
```

Comment: I don't want the method to return anything. This does not work for me.